# Difference checker, take input of file name instead of stating file

Tags: python, difference, difference-lists

So I have this code, It basically works fine if I specify a specific file to compare to:
but once I create a variable to allow a user to input the file name, and than compare I get the following errors.

Here is my code currently.

```
def open_file_and_return_list(file_path):
    list = []
    with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
        line = f.readline()
        while line:
            list.append(line)
            line = f.readline()
    return list


def clean_new_line(list):
    for i in range(len(list)):
        if "\n" in list[i]:
            list[i] = list[i].replace("\n", "")
    return list


if __name__ == "__main__":
    s1 = input("INFO: Select the first file to compare: ")
    s2 = input("INFO: Select the first file to compare: ")
    list1 = open_file_and_return_list(r"new.txt")
    list2 = open_file_and_return_list(r"standard.txt")
    maxl = max(len(list1), len(list2))
    list1 += [''] * (maxl - len(list1))
    list2 += [''] * (maxl - len(list2))
    diff = []
    diff_file = input("\nINFO: Select what to name the difference(s) : ")
    open(diff_file, 'w').close()

    for iline, (l1, l2) in enumerate(zip(list1, list2)):
        if l1 != l2:
            print(iline, l1, l2)
            print(iline, l1, l2, file=open(diff_file, 'a'))
```

The error I am getting is:

```
 list1 = open_file_and_return_list('r', s1)
 TypeError: open_file_and_return_list() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

I basically want to allow the user to state again the files to compare as they will always have different names and be "wild cards"

```
    s1 = input("INFO: Select the first file to compare: ")
    s2 = input("INFO: Select the first file to compare: ")
```

What am I doing wrong? Is my logic completely out of wack? Or are my glazed over eyes missing something small.

**EDIT**

The exact code I am running is:

```
elif device_type == "7":
print("\n")
print("************************************")
print("*****                          *****")
print("*****   Comparision Checker    *****")
print("*****    Of Two Configs        *****")
print("************************************")
print("\n")
print('\nWARNING: Discrepancies found:')


def open_file_and_return_list(file_path):
    list = []
    with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
        line = f.readline()
        while line:
            list.append(line)
            line = f.readline()
    return list


def clean_new_line(list):
    for i in range(len(list)):
        if "\n" in list[i]:
            list[i] = list[i].replace("\n", "")
    return list


if __name__ == "__main__":
    s1 = input("INFO: Select the first file to compare: ")
    s2 = input("INFO: Select the first file to compare: ")
    list1 = open_file_and_return_list(r"new.txt")
    list2 = open_file_and_return_list(r"standard.txt")
    maxl = max(len(list1), len(list2))
    list1 += [''] * (maxl - len(list1))
    list2 += [''] * (maxl - len(list2))
    diff = []
    diff_file = input("\nINFO: Select what to name the difference(s) : ")
    open(diff_file, 'w').close()

    for iline, (l1, l2) in enumerate(zip(list1, list2)):
        if l1 != l2:
            print(iline, l1, l2)
            print(iline, l1, l2, file=open(diff_file, 'a'))
```

As you notice, if I set filename to `standard.txt` and `new.txt` the code executes flawlessly, but the second I am attempting to add my own variables, it crashes.

Comment: The line that errored in your stack trace doesn't exist in code.

Comment: `def open_file_and_return_list(file_path):` - this function takes one argument called `file_path`. And then you're calling it: `open_file_and_return_list('r', s1)` with TWO arguments. That's an error. Also, your code doesn't have this call, please post the actual code you're running.

Comment: Hello jordanm, can you elaborate for someone who is fairly new to python/programming.

Comment: And no, if you can write `r"new.txt"`, this doesn't mean that `('r', s1)` is the same thing. In the latter case you can simply pass `s1` as the argument

Comment: @TheFriendlyCoder, BTW, Python has [a built-in library for computing diffs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html).

Comment: @ForceBru Thank you so much! and thank you jordanm, for more detailed logic. I am new, so please bare with me, but you guys are teaching me a lot. If you post it as an answer, i will give it a correct check mark because honestly, my eyes are so glazed over that I would have taken another hour to figure this out....overworked :)

Comment: @ForceBru the problem I noticed is using the diff lib, in python I am able to pull differences of files, but not specify what line and I was trying to use difflib before, but had lots of problems.....or maybe I am not at that python level yet, I can admit this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code:

```
list1 = open_file_and_return_list('r', s1)
```

Implies that the function is called `open_file_and_return_list()`, the first argument is `'r'`, and the second argument is `s1`. However, the function is defined at the top of the code as so:

```
def open_file_and_return_list(file_path):
```

which tells Python that the function should only allow one argument to be stored as the variable `file_path`. As a result, Python stores the `'r'` as the `file_path` and doesn't know what to do with the `s1` in the original function call.

Based on the way the rest of the code is written, it appears that the `'r'` was meant to be part of a statement like `r"new.txt"`. However, for the specific code provided in the question, the `'r'` is not needed and it should be possible to just pass in the file path stored in `s1`:

```
list1 = open_file_and_return_list(s1)
```